# how to determine Maximum Month Year and Month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that stores salary information (SALARY with fields such as NATIONAL_ID, SALYEAR, SALMONTH, SALAMOUNT, DATE_PAID, etc) for employees.

I need to extract data from that table including the last month an employee was paid a salary.

Unfortunately, DATE_PAID column is null for many cases in that table which forces me to think of using a combination of SALYEAR, SALMONTH to determine the highest value.

SALMONTH stores numbers from 1-12 and SALYEAR stores year information i.e 2010, 2015, etc.

Comment: SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What results do you want?  How should `NULL` values be handled?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`, we can try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NATIONAL_ID
                                   ORDER BY SALYEAR DESC, SALMONTH DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The above approach will target the latest record for each `NATIONAL_ID`, with "latest" being defined as having the most recent month in the most recent year.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(to_date(sal_year||to_char(sal_month,'FM00'),'yyyymm'))
```

should do it. The TO_DATE is really just for completeness if you want a date datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `COALESCE` like this:

```
SELECT MAX(COALESCE(YEAR(DATE_PAID) * 100 + MONTH(DATE_PAID), SALYEAR * 100 + SALMONTH))
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Correlated Sub Query -

```
with temp as (
    select national_id, 
    max(to_number(to_char(salyear)||lpad(to_char(salmonth),2,'0'))) as max_salmonthyear
    from salary
    group by national_id)
select *
from salary s, temp t
where s.national_id = t.national_id
  and to_number(to_char(salyear)||lpad(to_char(salmonth),2,'0')) = t.max_salmonthyear
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use aggregation?

```
select nationalid, max(salyear * 100 + salmonth) as salyearmonth
from t
group by nationalid;
```

If you want to convert the yearmonth to a date:

```
select nationalid,
       to_date(max(salyear * 100 + salmonth), 'YYYYMM') as salyearmonth
from t
group by nationalid;
```

This returns the first date of the salary month.